# Call Word and Compare 2 Word document versions from Excel Office Script

Tags: office-scripts, ms-office-script

Is it possible to call Word from an Excel Office Script and compare two versions of the same word document?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Office Scripts is currently only available in Excel. If you would like to see Office Scripts in Word, let us know here: http://aka.ms/ExcelSuggestions.

Thanks,

The Office Scripts team